# XCode using SVN protocol

Tags: xcode, macos, svn

I have a sublime server running on Windows server. Sublime only supports the svn protocol.

I am using XCode 4.2 currently, does anyone know how I can get either XCode to work with the svn protocol or change the SVN sublime to accept HTTP?

I already tried http://:3690/Repository/  but that didnt work.

Thanks

Comment: Why would `http://:3690/Repository/` work with anything? Does omitting the host imply `localhost` or something?

Comment: Sorry, the missing hostname is just my DNS server name that is put in there. I used 3690 because thats the port the svn protocol listens on.  The problem is, is there a way to get xcode to connect to SVN, when only the svn:// protocol can be used?

Comment: Well the documentation for Sublime suggests it can be configured to serve up repositories over HTTP http://www.sublimesvn.com/documentation/administrator-guide/configuring-sublime-with-apache.html

Comment: Yes, thank you. I saw that and I since then installed Apachi. So I installed SVNServer (Which uses Apache) and the repository I can access now via http:// in the browser and the terminal. Howeve, in the organizer under Repositorys when I try to connect, I just get the spinner....

Comment: Not sure why I got a -1? I already went down the route you suggested, which is I installed Apache already. So I already did my research and still dont have a solution...  I still just get a spinner when xcode trys to connect.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had to restart XCode. It seems like something was being cached. I can connect now.

Thanks for the help.